# Bancommand discord api (JDA5) gives an error

Tags: java, command, discord-jda, slash

I'm in the process of programming a Discord bot with JDA. At the moment I'm in the process of programming a ban command. If I enter on the Discord server: /ban @user (reason) (deletedays) it works quite well but if I only enter: /ban @user (reason) or /ban @user I get an error. I'm not sure where this error can come from. I hope someone can help me with this. Many Thanks.

**Main.java**

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException, InterruptedException {
        String token = "MYTOKEN";

        JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault(
                        token,
                        GatewayIntent.MESSAGE_CONTENT,
                        GatewayIntent.DIRECT_MESSAGES,
                        GatewayIntent.GUILD_MEMBERS,
                        GatewayIntent.GUILD_MESSAGES,
                        GatewayIntent.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
                        GatewayIntent.GUILD_VOICE_STATES,
                        GatewayIntent.GUILD_BANS
                )

                .setActivity(Activity.playing("mit Sally!"))
                .setStatus(OnlineStatus.ONLINE)
                //EventListeners
                .addEventListeners(new BanCommand())
                .build().awaitReady();

        System.out.println("======START======");

        Guild server = jda.getGuildById("GuildID");
        server.updateCommands().addCommands(
                Commands.slash("ban", "Ban a user.")
                        .addOption(OptionType.USER, "user", "User who should be banned.", true)
                        .addOption(OptionType.STRING, "reason", "Reason why the user get banned.")
                        .addOption(OptionType.INTEGER, "deldays", "Delete the messages from the user.", false)
        ).queue();


    }
}
```

**BanCommand.java**

```
public class BanCommand extends ListenerAdapter {

    public void onSlashCommandInteraction(SlashCommandInteractionEvent event) {
        if (event.getName().equals("ban")) {
            Member member = event.getOption("user").getAsMember();
            String reason = event.getOption("reason").getAsString();
            int deldays = event.getOption("deldays").getAsInt();

            if (!member.hasPermission(Permission.ADMINISTRATOR)) {
                member.ban(deldays, TimeUnit.DAYS).reason("reason").queue();
                event.reply("You banned " + member.getEffectiveName() + "! "  + "Reason: " + reason).queue();
            } else {
                event.reply("You can't ban an Admin!").queue();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've been trying to solve this problem for a few hours but just can't figure it out.

**ERROR**

```
[JDA MainWS-ReadThread] ERROR JDA - One of the EventListeners had an uncaught exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.ogbot.Commands.Admin.BanCommand.onSlashCommandInteraction(BanCommand.java:14)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter.onEvent(ListenerAdapter.java:424)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.InterfacedEventManager.handle(InterfacedEventManager.java:96)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handleInternally(EventManagerProxy.java:88)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.hooks.EventManagerProxy.handle(EventManagerProxy.java:70)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.JDAImpl.handleEvent(JDAImpl.java:171)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.InteractionCreateHandler.handleCommand(InteractionCreateHandler.java:112)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.InteractionCreateHandler.handleInternally(InteractionCreateHandler.java:83)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.handle.SocketHandler.handle(SocketHandler.java:39)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onDispatch(WebSocketClient.java:984)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onEvent(WebSocketClient.java:870)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.handleEvent(WebSocketClient.java:848)
    at net.dv8tion.jda.internal.requests.WebSocketClient.onBinaryMessage(WebSocketClient.java:1023)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ListenerManager.callOnBinaryMessage(ListenerManager.java:385)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.callOnBinaryMessage(ReadingThread.java:276)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleBinaryFrame(ReadingThread.java:996)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.handleFrame(ReadingThread.java:755)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.main(ReadingThread.java:108)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.ReadingThread.runMain(ReadingThread.java:64)
    at com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketThread.run(WebSocketThread.java:45)
```

I tried to give "user", "reason", "deldays" other names, I tried to output the text in an embed instead of reply and I created a new bot and copied the stuff in there, but that didn't work either. That was actually all.

Comment: You have a NullPointerException on line 14 in BanCommand.java. Make sure you're not calling a method on a potentially null object (like a missing/optional parameter).

Comment: Yes, I know that myself, but there is nothing in line 14.

Answer (score 1):

The `getOption(name)` method will return `null` when the option is not supplied. You need to properly check that instead of simply calling `getAsString()` or similar on it, since that is not possible on `null`.

You can also use `getOption("reason", OptionMapping::getAsString)` to avoid the null check, but then it will simply return null for the string.

Lastly, you can provide a fallback value to be used in the case that the option is not supplied:

```java
String reason = event.getOption("reason", "No reason specified", OptionMapping::getAsString);
```

See the documentation for details:

- [getOption(String, Function)](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA5/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/interactions/commands/CommandInteractionPayload.html#getOption(java.lang.String,java.util.function.Function))
- [getOption(String, String, Function)](https://ci.dv8tion.net/job/JDA5/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/api/interactions/commands/CommandInteractionPayload.html#getOption(java.lang.String,T,java.util.function.Function))